# VBA Error assigning markers after removing and readding SeriesCollection

Tags: excel, vba, charts, markers

I'm creating a template in which users input milestone dates and their associated status and it creates a timeline.  The code creates and plots several SeriesCollection (named "test" and "label") over the same axis on the Timeline.  I have a macro that allows users to click a command button and automatically clear all the Series Collections from the chart (leaving it blank).  However when I go to run the code which recreates the SeriesCollections "test" and "label" using the new user input info it has an error when it goes to assign the markerstyle to the points in Series Collection "test".
However if I click the Select Data button (which displays the SeriesCollections on the Chart) in Excel while its stuck at that line of code and then run the code in the Visual Basic Window it can now proceed forward and execute all the code properly and assign markers.

Why do I need to go into the Excel application and open the Select Data Window so the program can move forward?

```
     Sub clearchart()
    'removes all prior SeriesCollections from timeline chart

    Dim numseries As Integer
    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
        numseries = .SeriesCollection.Count
    For i = 1 To numseries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
    Next i
    End With
    End Sub
''''
''''
    Sub MarkerAssign()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim picname As String
    Dim imageaddress As String
    Dim ptnum As Integer

    ptnum = 1
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Date_Table3")
    tbl.ListColumns("Status").DataBodyRange.Select

    For Each cell In Selection
    If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then
    Else
    'markers assigned to seriescollection are images
    picname = markerstatus(cell)
    imageaddress = GetImage(picname)

    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
        .SeriesCollection("test").IsFiltered = False

    '!gets stuck here!
        .SeriesCollection("test").Points(ptnum).MarkerStyle = 
    xlMarkerStylePicture
            .SeriesCollection("test").Points(ptnum).format.Fill.UserPicture 
    imageaddress


        .SeriesCollection("label").Points(ptnum).DataLabel.Top = 25


    End With

    ptnum = ptnum + 1
    End If
    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.series.isfiltered): "When a user filters out a series, the series IsFiltered property switches to True, and the series is transferred out of its parent SeriesCollection". So that might be why you get stuck. The same source tells us that "..that series still remains in its parent FullSeriesCollection...", meaning using `.FullSeriesCollection` might work.

Answer (score 0):

[Found a post that provided a solution to my problem!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45132822/deleting-dataseries-in-a-chart-in-excel-vba-2016)

After running the code I was able to successfully assign markers to the new series